# Calling two functions one after other is failing in bash/sqlplus

Tags: linux, oracle, bash, sqlplus

I have two functions- ABC, XYZ. ABC deletes some rows in table1 as user1 and XYZ drops some users as DB User. First I am calling ABC and then XYZ. ABC function is being executed but at XYZ it is failing- "XYZ: command not found"

```
function ABC
{
        sqlplus -s $ur1/$pwd@$SID << EOF

        delete from table1 where row_name = 'A1';
        delete from table2 where row_name = 'A2';
        exit

        EOF
}

function XYZ
{
 sqlplus eip_dba/eip_dba$result@${input} << eof
 set timing off
 set serveroutput on size 10000
 set feedback off
 spool xyz_$input.out

 drop user usr1 cascade;
 drop user usr2 cascade;
 drop user usr3 cascade;
 commit;
 exit
 eof
}

ABC
XYZ

bash-3.2$ ./db_test.sh 

2 rows deleted.


2 rows deleted.

./db_test.sh: line 100: XYZ: command not found
```

Please let me know what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. I will use this tip before from now onwards.

Answer (score 4):

Try removing the whitespace before EOF

```
function ABC
{
        sqlplus -s $ur1/$pwd@$SID << EOF

        delete from table1 where row_name = 'A1';
        delete from table2 where row_name = 'A2';
        exit

EOF
}
```

I tried this in a sample program and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The format of here-documents is:

```
    <<WORD
here-document content ...
    here-document content ...
  here-document content ...
WORD
```

`WORD` can be any label you like, but the end marker must be the only thing on the line, no whitespaces before or after.

In your example functions you are using `eof` and `EOF` as labels, you should remove the space characters from in front of them so that they are really at the beginning of the line, like this:

```
function ABC
{
        sqlplus -s $ur1/$pwd@$SID << EOF

        delete from table1 where row_name = 'A1';
        delete from table2 where row_name = 'A2';
        exit

EOF
}

function XYZ
{
 sqlplus eip_dba/eip_dba$result@${input} << eof
 set timing off
 # ... and so on ....

eof
}
```

That is, the ending `EOF` and `eof` are right at the beginning of the line, with no trailing spaces either.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how can I insert code in the "Add Comment" area in stackoverflow? Every time I am starting a new thread. Instead I want to have a single thread with some additional questions about the same script.